# How to change user in hdfs using sparkSubmit in java

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark

I would like to change the user used in hdfs compared to the one that is used in the jvm because i have this error :

> Stream spark: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException:
>   Permission denied: user=www, access=WRITE,
>   node="/user/www/.sparkStaging/application_1460635834146_0012":hdfs:hdfs:drwxr-xr-x

And i want to change the user "www" to another like "joe" who had the permission to write. ( i haven't a folder "user/www", but i have "user/joe" )

Here is my java code :

```
    LOGGER.debug("start submitSparkJob");

    Process spark;
    SparkLauncher sl;
    try {
        sl = new SparkLauncher()
                .setAppName(argsMap.get(SparkParametersEnum.NAME))
                .setSparkHome(argsMap.get(SparkParametersEnum.SPARK_HOME))
                .setAppResource(argsMap.get(SparkParametersEnum.JAR))
                .setMainClass(argsMap.get(SparkParametersEnum.CLASS))
                .addAppArgs(argsMap.get(SparkParametersEnum.ARG))
                .setMaster(argsMap.get(SparkParametersEnum.MASTER))
                .setDeployMode(argsMap.get(SparkParametersEnum.DEPLOY_MODE))
                .setConf(SparkLauncher.DRIVER_MEMORY, "2g")
                .setVerbose(true);


            if(argsMap.containsKey(SparkParametersEnum.STAGING_DIR)){
                sl.setConf("spark.yarn.stagingDir", argsMap.get(SparkParametersEnum.STAGING_DIR));
            }
            if(argsMap.containsKey(SparkParametersEnum.ACCESS_NAMENODES)){
                sl.setConf("spark.yarn.access.namenodes", argsMap.get(SparkParametersEnum.ACCESS_NAMENODES));
            }
            if(argsMap.containsKey(SparkParametersEnum.PRINCIPAL)){
                sl.setConf("spark.yarn.principal", argsMap.get(SparkParametersEnum.PRINCIPAL));
            }
            if(argsMap.containsKey(SparkParametersEnum.DIST_JAR)){
                sl.setConf("spark.yarn.dist.jars", argsMap.get(SparkParametersEnum.DIST_JAR));
            }
       LOGGER.debug("SparkLauncher set");

        spark = sl.launch();

        LOGGER.debug("SparkLauncher launched");
```

I tried :

- Set the user with Systeme.setProterty("user.name","joe");
- Change the option  spark.yarn.stagingDir
- Change the option  spark.yarn.access.namenodes
- Change the option  spark.yarn.dist.jars

But none worked

Here you can see the strak trace:

```
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,794  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark: Parsed arguments:
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,794  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:   master                  yarn//*****
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,795  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:   deployMode              cluster
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,795  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:   executorMemory          null
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,795  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:   executorCores           null
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,795  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:   totalExecutorCores      null
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,795  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:   propertiesFile          /usr/hdp/2.3.0.0-2557/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,796  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:   driverMemory            2g
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,796  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:   driverCores             null
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,796  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:   driverExtraClassPath    null
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,796  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:   driverExtraLibraryPath  null
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,796  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:   driverExtraJavaOptions  null
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,796  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:   supervise               false
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,797  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:   queue                   null
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,797  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:   numExecutors            null
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,797  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:   files                   null
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,797  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:   pyFiles                 null
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,797  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:   archives                null
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,797  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:   mainClass               **********.ExtractLauncher
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,798  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:   primaryResource         file:/usr/*****/MyJar.jar
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,798  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:   name                    mySparkApp
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,798  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:   childArgs               [application-context.xml -s "2017-02-08" -e "2017-02-08" -t "******" -te "*****"]
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,798  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:   jars                    null
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,798  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:   packages                null
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,798  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:   repositories            null
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,799  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:   verbose                 true
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,799  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,799  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark: Spark properties used, including those specified through
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,800  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:  --conf and those from the properties file /usr/hdp/2.3.0.0-2557/spark/conf/spark-defaults.conf:
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,800  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:   spark.yarn.queue -> default
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,801  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:   spark.local.dir -> /hadoop/spark
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,801  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:   spark.history.kerberos.principal -> none
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,802  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:   spark.driver.memory -> 2g
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,802  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:   spark.yarn.max.executor.failures -> 3
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,802  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:   spark.yarn.historyServer.address -> ********:*****
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,803  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:   spark.yarn.services -> org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.history.YarnHistoryService
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,803  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:   spark.history.ui.port -> *****
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,804  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:   spark.history.provider -> org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.history.YarnHistoryProvider
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,804  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:   spark.yarn.scheduler.heartbeat.interval-ms -> 5000
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,805  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:   spark.yarn.submit.file.replication -> 3
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,805  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:   spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead -> 384
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,805  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:   spark.yarn.containerLauncherMaxThreads -> 25
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,806  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:   spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead -> 384
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,806  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:   spark.history.kerberos.keytab -> none
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,807  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:   spark.yarn.preserve.staging.files -> false
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,807  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,808  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,814  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark: Main class:
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,814  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark: org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,815  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark: Arguments:
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,815  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark: --name
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,815  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark: mySparkApp
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,815  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark: --driver-memory
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,815  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark: 2g
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,815  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark: --jar
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,816  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark: file:/usr/***/MyJar.jar
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,816  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark: --class
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,816  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark: **********.ExtractLauncher
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,816  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark: --arg
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,816  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark: application-context.xml -s "2017-02-08" -e "2017-02-08" -t "******" -te "******"
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,817  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark: System properties:
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,817  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark: spark.yarn.queue -> default
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,817  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark: spark.local.dir -> /hadoop/spark
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,817  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark: spark.history.kerberos.principal -> none
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,817  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark: spark.driver.memory -> 2g
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,818  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark: spark.yarn.max.executor.failures -> 3
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,818  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark: spark.yarn.historyServer.address -> ******:*****
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,818  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark: spark.yarn.services -> org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.history.YarnHistoryService
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,818  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark: spark.history.ui.port -> *****
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,818  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark: SPARK_SUBMIT -> true
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,818  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark: spark.history.provider -> org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.history.YarnHistoryProvider
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,818  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark: spark.app.name -> mySparkApp
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,819  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark: spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead -> 384
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,819  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark: spark.yarn.submit.file.replication -> 3
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,819  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark: spark.yarn.scheduler.heartbeat.interval-ms -> 5000
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,819  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark: spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead -> 384
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,819  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark: spark.yarn.containerLauncherMaxThreads -> 25
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,820  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark: spark.history.kerberos.keytab -> none
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,820  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark: spark.yarn.preserve.staging.files -> false
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,821  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark: spark.master -> yarn-cluster
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,821  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark: Classpath elements:
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,821  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,821  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:
15 Feb 2017 15:36:22,821  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:
15 Feb 2017 15:36:23,275  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark: 17/02/15 15:36:23 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
15 Feb 2017 15:36:23,796  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark: 17/02/15 15:36:23 INFO RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at *********:*******
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,030  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark: 17/02/15 15:36:24 INFO Client: Requesting a new application from cluster with 1 NodeManagers
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,043  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark: 17/02/15 15:36:24 INFO Client: Verifying our application has not requested more than the maximum memory capability of the cluster (5120 MB per container)
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,044  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark: 17/02/15 15:36:24 INFO Client: Will allocate AM container, with 2432 MB memory including 384 MB overhead
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,045  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark: 17/02/15 15:36:24 INFO Client: Setting up container launch context for our AM
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,046  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark: 17/02/15 15:36:24 INFO Client: Preparing resources for our AM container
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,364  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark: 17/02/15 15:36:24 WARN DomainSocketFactory: The short-circuit local reads feature cannot be used because libhadoop cannot be loaded.
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,402  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark: Error: application failed with exception
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,402  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark: org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: Permission denied: user=www, access=WRITE, inode="/user/www/.sparkStaging/application_1460635834146_0012":hdfs:hdfs:drwxr-xr-x
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,402  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:319)
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,402  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:292)
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,403  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:213)
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,403  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:190)
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,403  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPermission(FSDirectory.java:1698)
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,403  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPermission(FSDirectory.java:1682)
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,403  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkAncestorAccess(FSDirectory.java:1665)
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,403  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirMkdirOp.mkdirs(FSDirMkdirOp.java:71)
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,404  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.mkdirs(FSNamesystem.java:3895)
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,404  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.mkdirs(NameNodeRpcServer.java:983)
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,404  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.mkdirs(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:622)
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,404  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,404  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,404  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:969)
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,404  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2081)
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,405  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2077)
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,410  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,410  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:       at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,410  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,411  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2075)
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,411  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,414  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,414  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,414  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,414  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,414  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteException.java:106)
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,415  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:73)
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,415  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.primitiveMkdir(DFSClient.java:3010)
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,415  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.mkdirs(DFSClient.java:2978)
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,415  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$21.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1047)
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,415  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$21.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1043)
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,415  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,416  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.mkdirsInternal(DistributedFileSystem.java:1043)
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,416  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.mkdirs(DistributedFileSystem.java:1036)
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,416  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.mkdirs(FileSystem.java:1877)
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,416  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:       at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.mkdirs(FileSystem.java:598)
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,416  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:       at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.prepareLocalResources(Client.scala:224)
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,416  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:       at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.createContainerLaunchContext(Client.scala:384)
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,416  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:       at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.submitApplication(Client.scala:102)
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,417  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:       at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:619)
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,417  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:       at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.main(Client.scala:647)
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,417  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:       at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.main(Client.scala)
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,417  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,417  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,417  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,417  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,421  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:577)
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,421  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:174)
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,421  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:197)
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,422  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:112)
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,422  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:       at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,422  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark: Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException): Permission denied: user=www, access=WRITE, inode="/user/www/.sparkStaging/application_1460635834146_0012":hdfs:hdfs:drwxr-xr-x
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,422  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:319)
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,422  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.check(FSPermissionChecker.java:292)
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,422  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:213)
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,422  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSPermissionChecker.checkPermission(FSPermissionChecker.java:190)
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,422  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPermission(FSDirectory.java:1698)
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,423  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:       at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.checkPermission(FSDirectory.java:1682)
15 Feb 2017 15:36:24,432  [DEBUG] (InputStreamReaderRunnable.java:run:32): Stream spark:       ... 33 more
```

If someone has an idea :) 
Thanks !

Comment: Use chmod file for input file make it 770.

Comment: i haven't folder "user/www", but i have "user/joe"  i can't use chmod

Comment: do you have `/home/joe` on your local? if so try `sudo -i -u joe spark-submit <options>`

Comment: on my local, i haven't the user joe, and i can't create it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the following environment variable which will be used automatically:

```
export HADOOP_USER_NAME=<your hdfs user>
```

Also [mentioned here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-registry/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/registry/client/impl/zk/RegistryInternalConstants.html):

> **HADOOP_USER_NAME** 
>  This the Hadoop environment variable which
>   propagates the identity of a user in an insecure cluster

Comment: I need to do that on the local or on the server machine ? i think it's on the server machine, but i'm not sure

Comment: It worked for me when I set it on the machine running the spark code (in my case, IntellJ running spark code, or machine running spark-submit)

Comment: It works !!  Thank you  !!  
I was wrong, it is on the client machine that we have to do this command

Comment: How to add this command to code? I run code with IntellJ